# AVAudioPlayer play issue with two sounds as echo

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

I have a separate View Controller that holds some Audio Message (URL with mp3 files). Here's the code I use to start playing a message:

```
- (void)playAudioMsg
{
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient error: nil];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive: YES error: nil];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://blahblahblah.mp3"]];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error:nil];

    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
    audioPlayer.delegate=self;

    [audioPlayer play];
}
```

The first time I open this view controller and click on a message to play, it plays just fine.

Then I dismiss a view controller.

Then I open it again and click on the same audio message. And what happens it's **like two separate AVAudioPlayers got created** - one of which starts playing audio right away and another is with a one-second delay (it sounds like the first message plays with echo.

Most interesting is when I dismiss a view controller then one message stops playing and another one keeps playing in the background even though when dismissing a view controller, I call `[audioPlayer stop]`.

Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution.

The problem comes from the fact that when I call `-(void) playAudioMsg {...}` I do it using this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playAudioMsg) name:@"playAudioMsg" object:nil];
```

... which is declared inside `- (void) viewDidLoad {...}`. But then I totally forgot to remove that observer when leaving the ViewController:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"playAudioMsg" object:nil];

}
```

Without removing the observer and then coming back to the same page, it sets duplicate for the same observer, so the method `playAudioMsg` gets called twice.